# Выбрать все значения ячеек <td> при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно по нажатию на кнопку, которая в ячейке, отправить значения других ячеек той же строки на модальную форму. Нашел какой то код, он даже чего то выводит. Но что он выводит и как мне получить то что нужно - увы, незнаю.
Подскажите что мне загуглить чтобы понять что происходит в скрипте? Или объясните что происходит. Все никак руки не дойдут до изучения javascript а задачу поставленную выполнить нужно.

есть такая разметка:

```
<table id="checked-table" class="table table-bordred table-striped" align="center">
    <thead>        
    <tbody>        
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td width="20" align="center">
                <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```

и есть код:

```
$('.btn.btn-primary').click(function(){
    var tdVals = $(this).parent('td').siblings('td').map(function(i, td){
            return $(td).text();
        })
    console.log(tdVals);
});
```

Comment: Нужно исправить $(this).parent на $(this).parents. И будет все просто....  Выбрать нажатую кнопку, выбрать ее родителя с тегом td, у него взять всех соседий с тегом td и для каждого элемента из такого набора вернуть его содержимое ввиде текста...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так (https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.btn.btn-primary').click(function(){
    var tdVals = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map(function(i, td) {
        return $(td).text();
    });
    console.log(tdVals);
});
```

Если значение ячейки, где находится кнопка, получать не нужно, можно добавить элементу `td` какой-нибудь класс, например `exclude` и заменить селектор в методе `find`:

```
var tdVals = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(.exclude)').map( /* ... */ );
```